# What happened to the Trojan prologue in Neverwhere?

Tags: neil-gaiman, neverwhere

I used to have a copy of the book version of Neverwhere. It was the first or second edition that came out just after the original series broadcast. The book had a prologue in which Croup and Vandemar burn down Troy. It was very short, only a page or so long.

I lost that copy of the book somewhere over the years, but have bought other versions since. Every single one of them is missing that tiny prologue. What was the reason for its removal? I used to think it was just in American editions but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: From what I can find (I've not read the scene myself, but it was in for the BBC radio drama), it looks like the removal *started* in the American editions, and probably that edition got defaulted to other publishers in the UK from there.  I'm trying to find a source for the "author's preferred text" edition, which includes that bit as an extra, to see if there's any extra comments on the why.

Comment: It's in my 1996 BBC books edition - which I think is first edition. It's not about Troy - since it's in Tuscany. I can type it up if that helps - or if you'd just like to read it again.

Comment: @ImperatorHelvetica really?! That’s fascinating. It ends with Croup answering a phone call that’s clearly meant to be with Islington setting up the contract. I always thought it was odd that the contract was done several thousand years before the events of the story.

Comment: Wow. Maybe I'm confused. I've typed it up as an answer. I've only got the first edition - I keep lending out and losing the later one! It's not from the tiny How the Marquis got his coat back, is it? Could be I'm barking up entirely the wrong tree, though.

Comment: I've asked Neil. Hopefully he can chime in with an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The prologue with Croup and Vandermar in Tuscany was present in the original (first) edition by BBC. Later, when Avon Books wanted to publish it, Gaiman decided to revise it, adding clarifications here and there for things that would not be obvious for an non-British reader. As Gaiman explains in "Introduction to This Text" in author's preferred text,

> My editor at Avon Books, Jennifer Hershey, was a terrific and perceptive editor: our major disagreement as the jokes. She didn't like them, and was convinced that American readers would not be able to cope with jokes in a book that wasn't meant solely to be funny. **She wanted the second prologue gone**, too, in which we got to meet Croup and Vandermar for the first time, before the story began, and, although I missed it, I decided that she was right, and moved the description of them into the text. (It's reprinted here, at the back, in its original form, for the curious.)
>    <sub>Emphasis mine. Dated 28 July, 2005, from *Neverwhere: Author's preferred text*, published by Hadline Review.</sub>

Comment: Absolutely spot-on answer. And now we know who's to blame, although not *why*.

Comment: Well, given he's moved the descriptions of Croup and Vandermar to the text, this prologue seems redundant. Sadly, there's nothing else in this text which would tell us _why_.

Comment: Awesome. I wonder what other specific changes there were. It seems a little unfair to suggest that US readers can't understand jokes and I don't recall any jokes you need to be British to get.

Comment: If I had to guess at the reason, it's because Croup and Vandemar are much more menacing when you're forced to learn about them about them the same way the characters do - by being bloody terrified.

Answer (score 8):

> **Another Prologue – Four hundred years earlier**
>
> It was the middle of the sixteenth century, and it was raining in
>   Tuscany: a cold mean-spirited rain that turned the world grey.
>
> A smudge of black smoke rose towards the early-morning sky from the
>   little monastery on the hill. Two men sat on the hill, watching the
>   building begin to burn.
>
> 'That, Mister Vandemar' said the smaller of the, waving a greasy hand
>   towards the smoke, 'is going to be a very fine conflagration, as soon
>   as it conflagrates. Although a strict regard for truth would compel me
>   to confess my doubt that any of the inhabitants are going to be in a
>   position to fully and entirely appreciate it.'
>
> 'Because of being dead, you mean, Mister Croup?' asked his companion.
>   He was eating something that looked like it might once have been a
>   puppy, using his knife to slice large chunks off the carcass and place
>   them into his mouth.
>
> 'Because, as you so wisely point out, sage fellow, of being dead.'
>
> This is how you can tell the two speakers apart: firstly, when
>   standing up, Mr Vandemar is two and a half heads taller than Mr Croup.
>
> For secondly, Mr Croup has eyes of a faded china blue, while Mr
>   Vandemar's eyes are brown. For thirdly, while Mr Vandemar fashioned
>   the rings he wears on his right hand out of the skulls of four large
>   ravens, Mr Croup has no obvious jewellery.
>
> For fourthly, Mr Croup likes words, while Mr Vandemar is always
>   hungry.
>
> The monastery caught with a whoompf of air: it conflagrated.
>
> 'Don't like sage,' said Mr Vandemar. 'Tastes funny.'
>
> Someone screamed; and then there was a loud rumble, as the roof
>   collapsed, and roar as the flames rose high.
>
> 'Somebody wasn't dead,' said Mr Croup.
>
> 'Is now,' said Mr Vandemar, and he ate another slice of raw puppy. He
>   had found his lunch lying dead in a ditch, while they were walking
>   away from the monastery. He liked the sixteenth century. 'What's
>   next?' he asked.
>
> Mr Croup grinned, with teeth that looked like an accident in a
>   graveyard. 'About four hundred years from now,' he said. 'London
>   Below.'
>
> Mr Vandemar digested this, along with some puppy. At length, he asked,
>   'Kill people?'
>
> 'Oh yes,' said Mr Croup. 'I certainly think I can guarantee that.'

My guess as to why it was excised would be that it introduces time travel as a possibility – if Mr Croup and Mr Vandemar can jump from one atrocity to another, it causes no end of narrative headaches in their pursuit, in pacing when the fall of the House of Portico happened and in their banishment. If they can time-jump from 16th Century Tuscany to modern day London Below, then Door sending them 'A long, long way away' hardly stops them.

The characterisation of the pair is also repeated later, so we don't lose out by having it removed here and it might be said that it is Mr Croup's hunger (for porcelain) which is more relevant than Mr Vandemar's in letting the Marquis bribe him.

Its removal also allows the pair to be introduced with more mystery to Richard – brothers who are not brothers, the fox and the wolf, and it not being clear if they are of this world or not – even if there is something 'off' about them.

I can see why it could be cut, and why a publisher might do so, or askto insert it. Publishers are strange like that. So Gaiman might have wanted it removed from future editions, when he had more authorial clout.

The other thing is that it's a book written after the TV series, so it might relate to either a cut scene (filmed and discarded, or just written and not used) or a scene which happened. I don't recall one, but it has been a long time since I watched it.

Comment: Admittedly, they already can cause the exact same headache, since they seem to be wherever they wish to be at any given moment.  Either way, once they were falling far far away, it didn't seem to be something they could call upon, or they would have avoided dropping into the trap just as easy.  Nice answer though.